# Page is not reload when session is set if form is submit on fancy box

Tags: javascript, php

I am using a fancy box contains a form when I submit a form then fancy box is closed and session is set and another page call the session and checking if session is not empty then reload a page

Issue is that page is not reload when session is not empty.

Set the session on submit a form

```
$_SESSION['update1'] = $update1;
```

On form tag using this code for closing a fancy box

```
onsubmit="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();"
```

and on another page using this code for relaod a page

```
<?php 
$update_record = $_SESSION['update1'];
if($update_record !='' ){
unset($_SESSION['update1']);
?>
<script>
    location.reload();
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Add `session_start();` at the top of your script

Comment: On both pages??

Comment: still not working

Comment: print the session print_r($_SESSION) above $update_record and check whether you are getting all the session you require.